# React XSS Characters to HTML encode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, xss, html-encode

I've observed that React can HTML encode specific characters to prevent XSS vulnerabilities in certain contexts. For instance, consider the following code in **App.jsx**:

```js
function App() {
    const XSSProblematicChars = "><'\"()&:`";

    return (
        <>
            <h4>Displayed: {XSSProblematicChars}</h4>
            <img src={XSSProblematicChars}/>
        </>
    );
}
```

The corresponding HTML output would be:

```html
<h4>Displayed: &gt;&lt;'"()&amp;:`</h4>
<img src="><'&quot;()&amp;:`">
```

As demonstrated, HTML encoding varies depending on the context. For instance:

1. In the **h4** element, `<`, `>`, and `&` characters are encoded.
2. In the **src** attribute of the **img** element, `"` and `&` characters are encoded.

However, it's important to note that this encoding alone may not provide comprehensive protection against XSS attacks. To illustrate, consider the following **App.jsx** code. If the anchor element is clicked, the document's content can be altered using an XSS payload:

```js
function App() {
    const XSSPayload =
        "javascript:eval(atob('ZG9jdW1lbnQuYm9keS5pbm5lckhUTUw9JzxoMSBzdHlsZT0idGV4dC1hbGlnbjogY2VudGVyOyBwb3NpdGlvbjogYWJzb2x1dGU7IHRvcDogNTAlOyBsZWZ0OiA1MCU7IHRyYW5zZm9ybTogdHJhbnNsYXRlKC01MCUsIC01MCUpOyI+ISEhIEhBQ0tFRCAhISE8L2gxPic7'))";

    return (
        <>
            <a href={XSSPayload}>Click Me to Trigger XSS</a>
        </>
    );
}
```

This occurs because React fails to HTML encode the `:` character, allowing the use of `javascript:` syntax to trigger XSS.

To address this issue, I aim to create a function that will HTML encode all problematic characters in user input displayed on the frontend. Are there any other characters, like `:`, that React might have overlooked when encoding for HTML output?